# caffe runtest error after make all

Tags: testing, makefile, cpu, caffe, hdf5

I am installing caffe with ubuntu 16.04 system of cpu. I am facing prpoblem while makerun test.

The error is:

> ```
> src/caffe/test/test_hdf5data_layer.cpp:4:18: fatal error: hdf5.h: No such file or directory
> compilation terminated.
> Makefile:581: recipe for target 
> '.build_release/src/caffe/test/test_hdf5data_layer.o' failed
> make: *** [.build_release/src/caffe/test/test_hdf5data_layer.o] Error 1
> ```

Comment: is it possible you got similar error when `make` even before compiling and running the tests? it seems like you did not installed `hdf5` library. See installation instruction for more details.

Comment: while compiling make command i got errors too but i correct it.. how to install hdf5 lib.

Comment: Follow [these instructions](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/wiki/Ubuntu-16.04-or-15.10-Installation-Guide) you'll have hdf5 along with other dependencies there. make sure you complete each stage without errors.

Comment: Thank you. May i do all these steps from starting or realted to hdf5 file only.

Comment: I suppose if you `apt-get` an already existing package your sytem will know to ignore it. Just go over all the steps again, make sure you haven't skipped anything else. It shouldn't be too long or too complicated.